# can't configure urls from backend to frontend Yii2

Tags: yii2

Web frontend - localhost (directory apache2/htdocs in the LAMP), web backend - localhost:8080/backend (apache2/htdocs/backend). Yii advanced application in the same directory with htdocs - mafia-yii (apache2/mafia-yii). File main.php in backend/config:

```
'components' => [
    ....
    'urlManager' => [
        // here is your normal backend url manager config
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'baseUrl' => 'http://localhost/backend',
    ],
    'urlManagerFrontend' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'hostInfo' => 'http://localhost',
        'baseUrl' => 'http://localhost',
    ],

],
```

file ~/lampstack-7.0.4-0/apache2/mafia-yii/backend/views/layouts/main.php :

```
....
$menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Backend', 'url' => ['/site/index']];
$menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Fronend', 'url' => [Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontend->createUrl('/site/index')]];
....
```

**Result:**
http://localhost:8080/backend/index.php?r=backend%2Findex.php%3Fr%3Dsite%252Findex

Not Found (#404)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem. **Because:**

```
$var[] = Yii::getAlias('@webroot');
$var[] = Yii::getAlias('@web');
\yii\helpers\VarDumper::dump($var);
```

**returns:**
[ 0 => '/home/kira/lampstack-7.0.4-0/apache2/htdocs/backend' 1 => '/backend' ]

**the solution is:**
    $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Frontend', 'url' => '@web/../'];

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with:

```
'components' => [
    ....
    'urlManager' => [
        // here is your normal backend url manager config
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'baseUrl' => '/backend',
    ],
    'urlManagerFrontend' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'hostInfo' => 'http://localhost',
        'baseUrl' => '',
    ],

],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code:

```
use yii\helpers\Url;

$menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Fronend', 'url' => Url::to(Yii::getAlias('@web') . '/site/index', true)];
```

Comment: Result:
http://localhost:8080/backend/site/index

Not Found (#404)

it returns as @web - "/backend"

Comment: Then please try to use Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontend->createUrl('/site/index') after 'urlManagerFrontend' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'hostInfo' => 'http://localhost',
        'baseUrl' => '',
    ],
configuration instead of Url::to(